# About Angular4 subscribed data

Tags: angular, primeng

I am angular4 beginner and I want to ask about getting subscribed data.

This component has makeTableInfo() method.
This makeTableInfo() method is to make primeng turbotable.

I want to get column data and row data in makeTableInfo but those column and rows get undefined.

I think makeTableInfo() method run before get column data and column data.

so my guess is wait until retrieve column data and row data.

but I don't have idea to solve this yet.

Would you give me some advice to achieve my goal?

```
export class SerializeComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    tableSetting: TableSetting;
    settingA: TableSetting;
    settingB: TableSetting;
    rows: Bom[] = [];
    cols: ColumnSettings[] = [];
    userId: string;
    url: string;
    area: string;

    constructor(
        private notifyService: NotifyService,
        private router: Router,
        private tableService: TableService,
        private localStorageService: GridService
    ) {}

    makeTableInfo(
        userId,
        url,
        area,
        rowDataPath,
        columnDataPath,
        reorderableColumns,
        resizableColumns,
        paginator,
        paginatorRows
    ): any {
        let rows;
        let columns;
        this.tableService.setColumnDataPath(columnDataPath);
        this.tableService.setRowDataPath(rowDataPath);
        this.tableService.getRowData().subscribe((rowData) => {
            ⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎　can't get rows ⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎
            rows = rowData;

            this.tableService
                .getColumnSetting()
                .subscribe((initData) => {
                    ⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎ can't get columns ⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎⬇︎
                    columns = initData;
                });

                return new TableSetting(
                        userId,
                        url,
                        area,
                        resizableColumns,
                        reorderableColumns,
                        columns,  // ← undefined
                        rows,     // ← undefined
                        paginator,
                        paginatorRows,
                        columnDataPath
                );

        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.userId = 'user01';

        this.url = this.router.url;

        const areaA = 'upper';
        const rowDataPathA = 'aaa/aaa/data.json';
        const columnDataPathA = 'bbb/bbb/column.json';
        const reorderableColumnsA = false;
        const resizableColumnsA = false;
        const paginatorA = true;
        const paginatorRowsA = 10;

        this.settingA = this.makeTableInfo(
            this.userId,
            this.url,
            areaA,
            rowDataPathA,
            columnDataPathA,
            reorderableColumnsA,
            resizableColumnsA,
            paginatorA,
            paginatorRowsA
        );
    }
}
```

this is tableservice

```
@Injectable()
export class TableService {
    columnDataPath: string;
    rowDataPath: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    setColumnDataPath(columnDataPath: string) {
        this.columnDataPath = columnDataPath;
    }

    setRowDataPath(rowDataPath: string) {
        this.rowDataPath = rowDataPath;
    }

    getColumnSetting(): Observable<ColumnSettings[]> {
        console.log('columnDataPath = ', this.columnDataPath);
        if (!this.columnDataPath) {
            return
        }
        return this.http
            .get(
                this.columnDataPath
            )
            .map((data) => {
                return data as ColumnSettings[];
            });
    }

    getRowData(): Observable<Bom[]> {
        console.log('rowDataPath = ', this.rowDataPath);
        if (!this.rowDataPath) {
            return
        }
        return this.http
            .get(
                this.rowDataPath
            )
            .map((data) => {
                console.log('bom data = ', data);
                return data as Bom[];
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an error because variables: rows and columns not exist anymore when the data comes back from the server. Move them in to top of SerializeComponent (or use the variables you already have). In makeTableInfo before rows and columns variable add this. to appeal to them
e.g.:

```
export class SerializeComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  tableSetting: TableSetting;
  settingA: TableSetting;
  settingB: TableSetting;
  rows: Bom[] = [];
  cols: ColumnSettings[] = [];
  userId: string;
  url: string;
  area: string;

  constructor(
    private notifyService: NotifyService,
    private router: Router,
    private tableService: TableService,
    private localStorageService: GridService
  ) {}

  makeTableInfo(
    userId,
    url,
    area,
    rowDataPath,
    columnDataPath,
    reorderableColumns,
    resizableColumns,
    paginator,
    paginatorRows
  ): any {
      this.tableService.setColumnDataPath(columnDataPath);
      this.tableService.setRowDataPath(rowDataPath);
      this.tableService.getRowData().subscribe((rowData) => {
        this.rows = rowData;

        this.tableService
            .getColumnSetting()
            .subscribe((initData) => {
                this.columns = initData;
            });

            return new TableSetting(
                    userId,
                    url,
                    area,
                    resizableColumns,
                    reorderableColumns,
                    columns,  // ← undefined
                    rows,     // ← undefined
                    paginator,
                    paginatorRows,
                    columnDataPath
            );

    });
}

.....
```